# In irb, how do I 'require a library'

Tags: ruby

I'm following a book called the "Beginner's Guide to Ruby" and I'm afraid I'm not sure what 'requiring a library' means.

In my applications root directory I have a file called wordplay.rb and a I know how to start irb in Terminal. But I don't know how to

'use irb and require in the wordplay library'

Comment: Make sure you run `irb --help` so that you are aware of your options.  You can simply do `irb -rwordplay.rb` and then you will be ready to go.

Comment: @vgoff, thanks bear that in mind

Comment: Also, minus for literally no reason at all.

Comment: Probably for not checking the obvious documentation.  It happens.  It ends up being a plus if you learned something though.  Don't keep score here.  Keep score for you.

Comment: I gave a plus just because the minus was stupid...  At the end of the day beginners sometimes don't know where to find the documentation and the docs aren't always easy to understand especially for a beginner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the directory `wordplay.rb` is in, run `irb` and enter:

```
irb(main):001:0> require './wordplay'
```

Hopefully it will come back saying:

```
=> true
```

which means that the file was loaded successfully.

If it doesn't say 'true', it means that you still have to install a Ruby Gem which provides the library.  To install a gem, you have to type this in your shell:

```
 gem install wordplay     # or whatever your gem is called
```

Answer (score 1):

Requiring means taking a file's content and inserting it wherever you're requiring it in. Require with `require './path/to/wordplay'`

Comment: `require_relative` requires a library relative to the currently executing file. In IRb, there is no currently executing file, so, `require_relative` will simply `raise` an error.